# Embedded MongoDb Insertion using node js array insertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

Hello every one below I have node JS script and embedded MongoDb schema, I have inserted array data using node JS query as below I have mentioned but it stored empty array as I display below

1).   Node js

```
  try{
       // var quiz = levelScoreQuiz.child;
        var userObj = {

        'child.quiz_level.level_attempted.array.$push(level_score)': req.params.score

            //date: req.params.date
        };
        var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);
        user.save(function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err)}
        else{
            console.log("User score saved successfully");
            res.json(result);
        }
        });

        }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the reuslt ' +err);
        return next(err);
        }
```

2).      MongoDb Schema

```
var userScore = new Schema({

    child: {

        /*quiz:{type:Array,type:Object, 
                question_id1:{type:String}, 
                question_id2:{type:String}, 
                question_id3:{type:String}, 
                score:{type:Number}
        },*/
        quiz_level:{
            current_level:{type:Number},
            level_attempted:{type:Array,
                level_id:{type:Number},
                level_complete:{type:Boolean},
                level_score:{type:Number}

         }
        }
    }

});
```

Json

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "577f6d687fc74a8a179678f1",
  "child": {
    "quiz_level": {
      "current_level": 1,
      "level_attempted": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not mentioned what does this function do.

```
var user = new levelScoreQuiz(userObj);
```

Also this is totally absurd. How can you use a code as array key.

```
var userObj = {

    'child.quiz_level.level_attempted.array.$push(level_score)': req.params.score

        //date: req.params.date
    };
```

You might want to do this.

```
var userObj = {

    'quiz_level': req.params.score

        //date: req.params.date
    };
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir, but i am using embedded schema in node js and i am trying to store value coming from front end to my back end node js to mongodb as      level_attempted:{type:Array,
            level_id:{type:Number},
            level_complete:{type:Boolean},
            level_score:{type:Number}

     }  using the query in node js as child.quiz_level.level_attempted.array.$push(level_score)': req.params.score   is there is any possibility to store the value inside the array. Please give your suggestion it is helpful to me.